# How to pull pagination getStaticPaths in a inner category url_slug with react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm stuck with the returning paths value from the getStaticPaths()

the pagination works from the root folder, but if i have a sub category and then with a pagination, it will not work..

the error keeps showing

> Server Error Error: A required parameter (url_slug) was not provided
> as a string in getStaticPaths for /blogs/tag/[url_slug]/pages/[page]

[image]

This is how my files arrangement are..

This url works
http://localhost:3000/blogs/pages/2/

works but if this url, it will not work..
http://localhost:3000/blogs/tag/feedback-500/pages/2/
I need this url to work instead.

This is my code on the /blogs/tag/feedback-500/pages/2/

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const news = await Collection('blogs');

    const blog_taggings = await Collection('blog_taggings');
    const all_blog_taggings = blog_taggings.orderBy('publish_date').getItems();

    const all_paginations = news.getPages(2);
    const all_currentPage = news.getPageItems(params.page, 2)

    return { props: { all_blog_taggings, all_paginations, all_currentPage, global: global.toJson() } };
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const blogsPagesPaths = (await Collection('blogs')).getPages(5);
    return {
        paths: blogsPagesPaths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

The question would be, how can i make http://localhost:3000/blogs/tag/feedback-500/pages/2/ work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/blogs/pages/[page]` requires only one parameter which is `page`. 
However `/blogs/tag/[url_slug]/pages/[page]` requires two which are `url_slug` and `page`
 But here the issue is that you are only returning the page parameter

> A required parameter (url_slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /blogs/tag/[url_slug]/pages/[page]

So your returned `paths` property should be an array of  :

```js
params: {
   url_slug: "example",
   page: "example",
}
```

Not an array of :

```js
params: {
   page: "example",
}
```

you have to include all the possible pair values of `url_slug` and `page` so if you can get the corresponding `url_slug` of `page` from the `page` object this is good since you will have to map only through pages and include only the necessary objects

```js
export function getStaticPaths() {
  const pagesPossiblesValues = [
    {
      id: 1,
      slug: "first_slug",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      slug: "second_slug",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      slug: "third_slug",
    },
  ];

  return {
    paths: pagesPossiblesValues.map((element) => ({
      params: { page: element.id, url_slug: element.slug },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

However if this is not possible you should make two loops to make sure you have all the possible combinations for the page/slug pair values :

```js
 const pagesPossiblesValues = [
    {
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
    },
  ];
  const slugPossiblesValues = [
    {
      slug: "first",
    },
    {
      slug: "second",
    },
    {
      slug: "third",
    },
  ];
 let final = [];

 pagesPossiblesValues.forEach((page) => {
    slugPossiblesValues.forEach((slug) => {
      final.push({ params: { page: page.id, url_slug: slug.slug } });
    });
  });

  return {
    paths: final,
    fallback: false,
  };
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I almost got it. its not showing anymore error. however, im getting duplicates of the items now

Comment: I don't have any idea about your response but you don't get duplicate items in the mentioned approach

Comment: i'ved just edited my original question.. can you took a final look the reason i may be getting duplicates?

Comment: I can see that there is no duplicate items. each page value has every possible url_slug thats exactly what the paths should look like. Do you got any  errors ?

Comment: i got no errors, but the items that keep rendering on each page is the same item.. i can see that the pages link is working

Comment: This is an issue with your getStaticProps make sure you are destructing the correct value of the page and of the slug from params

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252493/discussion-between-ahmed-sbai-and-teik-cheah).